# CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired on all flutter apps

Tags: android, flutter

I am getting `CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: certificate has expired` in all network calls (including `Network_image` calls) - all my flutter apps even the old ones.

All apps were working fine but I don't know what caused this error. Other apps are working fine (Chrome , facebook , ..)

I also checked phone Date & time.
My flutter version is Flutter 1.12.13+hotfix.5 • channel stable •

Comment: Did you ever figure out what to do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are making requests to a server you manage?

Try testing your server with this tool: https://www.ionos.com/tools/ssl-checker and see if it says that it is "not installed correctly".

If you find that it has been working historically but recently stopped, you likely have an invalid chain of trust. [Recently, a common root CA certificate expired.](https://support.sectigo.com/articles/Knowledge/Sectigo-AddTrust-External-CA-Root-Expiring-May-30-2020) Your server may be using this and sending it as part of it's chain of certificates it sends to clients. If that is the case, and it is this recently-expired root CA, your fix will  most likely look like **removing that root certificate from your bundle**. So you'd include the intermediate certificates still, but exclude the root. You can then use these tools to revalidate if things are setup correctly.

You can also see the chain and some of the validity information using this tool: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html

Comment: Thank you for answering, I don't think that is the problem because the app is working fine when I run it on another device.
And I am having the same problem in different Flutter apps with different servers, so I don't think that all of the servers having the same SSL Certifcate problem.

Comment: Have you ran the tests I linked to against the URL?

Comment: Yes I ran it, the answer was The certificate is installed correctly.
I am sure the problem it is not a server problem.
Thank you again for helping